# Color of border based on domain model?

Tags: c#, wpf, domain-model

I have a poco class in my domain model:

```
public class Slot
{
    bool HasPlayed { get; set; }
}
```

And I am displaying it in a listbox item template.

```
<Border Background="...">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=HasPlayed, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Border>
```

But what I want to do is when the HasPlayed is true, the background color of the border turns red, and when false it's green. These brushes are in a resource dictionary.

I could add a Brush to the domain model, but that defeats the seperation of concerns. I also am NOT going to use the checkbox in the future, this is just a mock up UI.

I've tried a IValueConverter, but it doesn't change when the property changes. The model does implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

How would you change the color when the property changes?

Comment: What does your IValueConverter code look like?

Comment: It colors the border initially, but when the change to the property happens, it does not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a DataTrigger to trigger the action:

http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Data_Triggers

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the property change isn't being picked up because Slot doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Try something like this:

```
public class Slot : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _hasPlayed;

        private bool HasPlayed
        {
            get { return _hasPlayed; }
            set
            {
                _hasPlayed = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasPlayed"));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

The value you pass into your converter appears to be a `Slot`, so the binding does not point to the property that changes, for the binding to update however the binding needs to specify a path which points to the relevant property, in this case `HasPlayed`. (And the object owning the property of course needs to implement [INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), but you said that is the case already, correct?)